# How can you retrieve entries with a specific locale in a plugin?

Tags: localization, ajax, entries-field

I have this:

```
$this->requireAjaxRequest();

$segments = craft()->request->getActionSegments();

$lang = $segments[2];

$entryId = $segments[3];

$entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById( $entryId );

$response = array(
    'titre' => $entry->typeChambre,
    'etage' => $entry->etage->label,
    'surface' => $entry->surface,
    'loyer' => $entry->loyer,
    'charges' => $entry->charges,
    'description' => $entry->description,
    'photos' => $entry->photosChambre
);

$this->returnJson($response);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use an [ElementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel):

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->id = $entryId;
$criteria->locale = $lang;
$entry = $criteria->first();

if ($entry)
{
    $response = array(
        'titre' => $entry->typeChambre,
        'etage' => $entry->etage->label,
        'surface' => $entry->surface,
        'loyer' => $entry->loyer,
        'charges' => $entry->charges,
        'description' => $entry->description,
        'photos' => $entry->photosChambre
    );

    $this->returnJson($response);
}
```